# Microsoft Text To Speech Infinite Await in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, text-to-speech

```
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("", "westeurope");
        var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config);
        var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(xmlFirstPart + voice + xmlSecondPart + synthesisText + xmlThirdPart);
        var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);

        string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName + ".wav");
        await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync(file);
```

Hello, this snippet of code works with the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech NuGet in Visual Studio - it outputs the requested string to audio. The problem is that after outputting the audio, the program freezes. I presume that the third line of code is where the issue is, as the await function does not end, even though it completed its job. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could be because your PC isn't powerful enough to process it. Maybe reply to this comment with your hardware and I'll investigate.

Comment: I have about 30 gigabytes of free space;
CPU - Intel Core i7-5930K CPU 3.5GHz
RAM - 32GB RAM
GPU - 1080Ti
Does the program run on your computer?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try add a minimal reproduceable version so I can test it. I have the following: Ryzen 7 3800XT,  2080 SUPER, 1TB NVME SSD, 16 GB 3200MHZ RAM

Comment: Do you run this code fragment from a GUI application (given xamarin probably yes) or command line? Use a debugger to see if you really "hang" where you think you do. Try to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your `await` invocations.

Comment: Christian, adding .ConfigureAwait(false) was the solution to my problem. Thank you very much, cheers.

Comment: Good. I figured it would. You had a deadlock because that code ran on the UI thread. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). I don't want to provide a link-only answer. You could answer your own question and accept that answer so it doesn't linger open.